# QPixmap possible leak seen on Activity Monitor Mac OS X

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qpixmap, activity-monitor

I have a problem with QPixmap in Qt 4.7 on snow leopard 10.6.7 if it helps.

```
QPixmap *pix = new QPixmap("image.png");
delete pix;
```

Still, Activity Monitor shows me that the Real Memory usage for my application increases ...
As the QPixmap was never deleted.
I tested it by iterating the process and create/delete 50 pixmaps in a for loop.

Is it a Qt leak or is activity monitor crazy ?

Thank you !

Comment: You should use instruments (available with the developer tools, xcode) will give you a much better in-depth solution to the memory leak.

Comment: I know, but this should not leak at all it is a simple new/delete.

Comment: Just curious if his is Activity Monitor issue rather than Qt. Can you try to allocate a big chunk of data using any other class and see if Activity Monitor frees that memory ? Say: char* buf = new char[20971520]; delete [] buf; - that should be around 20Mb of memory and should be noticeable

Comment: Well activity monitor is just crazy. I did test new double[209715000200];
Nothing changed in real memory but the virtual memory did change.
I guess the real memory is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

What tool did you use to check this?
Basically, you shouldnt use the system monitor to check memory leaks, especially for a single line allocation, there are dedicated tools for that.

Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: I know Valgrind, my question was about activity monitor. It is much easier to see while you're coding the average memory occupation that to launch valgrind.
I hope activity monitor is wrong, but I want to be sure.